# Running SQL and Python on a webpage

Tags: python, sql, ssms, html

just a general question.
I have written some Python codes in Spider.  In my code, I use sql command to pull data from ssms then use Python to manipulate them.  Now I want to implement my codes on a webpage or other online sources so other can run them.  How would be possible?  Any thought would be appreciate :) Thanks!

P.S I'm a PC user not MAC

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks May be of help.

Comment: Perhaps you could use CGI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to a list of Python-based web frameworks:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

I know people who like Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/), and it has some thoughtful-looking Windows installation instructions here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/installation/#installation.

Also, you might also look at the Python library `pyodbc` to directly make your queries if I understand you right that you're using `sqlcmd`.